# How can I trigger the redraw of a QTableView inQt5?

Tags: qt5, repaint, qtableview, qtimer

I have implemented a simple `QAbstractTableModel` and attached it to a `QTableView` in Qt5. How can I trigger a repaint from a timer? The data changes every second?

My naïve attempt does not work (no repaint occurs):

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),table,SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data changes you should emit the dataChanged signal from the model.